# WPF: How to animate fading Image Change?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, wpf-controls, fading

I'm new to WPF Transforms and storyboard.

How can I change and image in an image object, to a different image by fading the old image and then bringing up the new image? what I want is something like this: [example](http://cryengine.com/)

notice how the image changes - that is what I want.

How could I create this affect in WPF? put two images in the same place and change their opacity?

Comment: If both should be visible at the same time, you could put two Image controls in a common Panel (e.g. a Grid) and animate their Opacities, the fading out one from 1 to 0, the fading in one from 0 to 1.

Comment: I thought about that, but isn't there another way like double animation or color animation?

Comment: You would use a DoubleAnimation for the Opacity property of the Image controls.

Comment: right, but couldn't I do it without putting two image controls? because if I want to change more than two images - 3 or 4, that would make have to use 4 different image controls, and is much harder to maintain. I thought there might be a way with `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` and change the source some how that it would change&fade

Comment: That was my initial question, is it required to see two images (the one fading out and the one fading in) at the same time? If not, you can of course use a single Image control, fade the image out, than set the new one and fade it in.

Comment: Yes it is. I want the effect like in the link I provided - one image fades, and another comes up.

Comment: yes its required. isn't there a built in way for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a control for a Windows Universal app that does that:

```
public sealed class ImageButton : Button, IFadeable
{
    public event EventHandler FadeoutCompleted;
    private Image _image;
    private Image _image2;
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ImageSource SecondImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SecondImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SecondImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public ImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ImageButton);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _image = GetTemplateChild("Image") as Image;
        _image2 = GetTemplateChild("Image2") as Image;
    }
    public void Fadeout()
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 1.0,
            To = 0.0,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        };

        var easingFunction = new CubicEase();
        easingFunction.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut;
        animation.EasingFunction = easingFunction;
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _image);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Opacity");

        storyboard.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (FadeoutCompleted != null)
            {
                FadeoutCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            _image2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _image.Opacity = 1.0;
        };
        _image2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        storyboard.Begin();

    }
}

public interface IFadeable
{
    void Fadeout();
    event EventHandler FadeoutCompleted;
}
```